# equivalent of Apple's UDID in windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, push-notification

is there any equivalent of the UDID in windows phone, 
im working on project that connect to a web server (NOT AZURE), and i want to use push notifications,
in apple there is a UDID i use so i can send a notification to that ID, the notification goes to Apple notification servers and then send it to the device.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone device ID is an array of 20 bytes. Internally, it's probably a MD5 hash of something.

```
byte [] DeviceID()
{
    object o;
    if (!DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out o))
       return null;
    return (byte[])o;
}
```

Feel free to format it as hex or Base64 if you need a text representation.

You'll need to declare the capability in the manifest, otherwise the function above would error out on a real device:

```
<Capabilities>
  ...
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
</Capabilities>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much, this really helped me :D

one more thing, the string parameter in the TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out o) is it static or it depends of an ID
so is the capability name.

Comment: It's static, and so is capability name. Click on the link below, the class `DeviceExtendedProperties` is perfectly documented. Also, if it helped, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.